# Getting information about the system proxy

Tags: android, proxy

I'm using `HttpClient` on my android application. Some user can have a system proxy configured on his device. How do I get the information?
From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503437/android-httpclient-doesnt-use-system-proxy-settings) I know you can do something like:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("someproxy", 8080);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

The problem is that I don't know where to find hostname of the proxy and the port.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

String proxyString = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.HTTP_PROXY);

if (proxyString != null)
{   
    String proxyAddress = proxyString.split(":")[0];
    int proxyPort = Integer.parseInt(proxyString.split(":")[1]);
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyAddress, proxyPort);

    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
}
```

I did not test through. Found [here](http://issue1273.blogspot.com/2011/11/may-force-be-with-you-use.html).