# continuing problems with AVD and fiddler

Tags: android, fiddler

the code below has two lines that were suggested to solve the problem where fiddler cannot see a post taking place in the AVD emulator.  Without the two lines the post is successful but fiddler cannot see it.  With the two lines the post comes back after about 10 minutes with an I/O exception.

```
    public HttpResponse postData() 
{ 
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header 

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/api/GETTrafficDirector"); 
    HttpResponse response = null; 

    //do these two lines so fiddler can see post when debugging
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("192.168.2.8", 8888); 
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy); 


    try { 
            // Add your data 
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345")); 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!")); 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 

            // Execute HTTP Post Request 
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 

        } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { 
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    } 
    return response;
```

Comment: can you add a screen shot of your Fiddler settings? And your emulator APN settings? It definitely worked on my machine but I was scientifically changing all the settings all at once so might have missed a change

Comment: Paul: Sure, here they are: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/39662979/fiddlerAVDSettings.png

Comment: fiddler looks right... to avoid chance of weird conflicts proxy IP in APN should be same as in code above and username and password in APN should be blank.