# Android HTTP Connection refused

Tags: android, http

I am trying to access from an Android device over WiFi a local web server which I can access from my laptop either on the browser, or using curl. I can also access the server on the android device browser.

The code I am using to access the server yields a **"connection refused"** exception.

This is the code:

```
public void getController1() {
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.169:8000");
  HttpResponse response = null;
  System.out.println(httpget.toString());
  try {
    response= httpclient.execute(httpget);
    txtViewStatus.setText("Controller 1 - OK"+response);
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    txtViewStatus.setText("Controller 1 - Error"+e);
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have the internet permission in your manifest ?

Comment: to be clear, you can access `192.168.1.169:8000` from the browser of the device that gives you `connection refused`?

Comment: Yes, I do have INTERNET permission in the manifest.

Comment: Yes, I can access the server from the device browser that give the connection refused.

Comment: It's your webserver that does not like your request. Might be caused by not specifying a user-agent. You could try it with `HttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android")` which will set that to "Android" and also have some nicer defaults than the `DefaultHttpClient`

Comment: Same behavior using the AndroidHttpClient instead of the DefaultHttpClient

Comment: Problem solved. The issue was a corrupted manifest file. I deleted the permission lines and re-typed them in and now the problem is gone.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue was a corrupted manifest file. I deleted the permission lines and re-typed them in and now the problem is gone

Comment: Another common cause of this issue is having a proxy turned on. Make sure there is no proxy enabled on your device too.

Answer (score 9):

I was missing permission; you should check manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>    
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

Comment: you could simplify requesting the permissions if you write out `<uses-permission` once and then indent the rest of the requests.

Answer (score 4):

Check your internet connection strength.

For my case the network connection is low so this error thrown.

Comment: thanks mate, my wifi was off. could've spent hours debugging

Comment: when googling on the same device where the studio is running.

Answer (score 3):

Past this to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Please add a little more explanation and, if possible, documentation links.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be because you're using a proxy? The proxy issue is discussed in [Android HttpClient Doesn't Use System Proxy Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503437/android-httpclient-doesnt-use-system-proxy-settings) (see the answer by CommonsWare).

Answer (score 0):

you should enable pc suite in android device :

```
1: set http url in android app e.g ("http://192.168.1.100:81/api/droid/getdata")
laptop or pc wifi ip is (192.168.1.100)
2: connect android device to pc or laptop in usb port
3: goto this setting in android device setting -> more -> Tethering and portable hotspot -> pc suite(HiSuite)
4: run android app
```

this work good