# Spring Android Connection Refused ECONNREFUSED

Tags: android, spring, rest, android-permissions

I am trying to make a connection from my Android to my local machine on a wifi network. My machines wifi ip address is 10.27.27.172 and I am running my node.js server on port 7890. I can use my phones chrome browser and browse to my server and access some endpoints which return json. My problem comes when I try and use spring-android rest template. I have given INTERNET permissions to my android application but I still get a ECONNREFUSED error. Is this an android port issue? Is the firewall blocking my request. If so why can I browse to the server but not use the REST client to get the information?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer on [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469060/android-http-connection-refused). You need to make sure you retype the  I guess the eclipse editor sometimes adds in invisible characters or something. Anyways it is working now.