# AndroidHttpclient connection refused

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

i have a strange problem with AndroidHttpClient.
Sometimes i got the error connection refused on the same internal webservice. 
In the access log on my server I have no log entry for the request, so it seems that the server is not called. Connection with wifi is ok.

I tried to connect to different servers, the problem occurs on other servers too. 
Has anyone an explanation for this?

Code:

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 120000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 120000);

AndroidHttpClient httpclient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setParams(httpParams);

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: you are using the emulator?

Comment: No, I am not using the emulator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android HTTP Connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469060/android-http-connection-refused)

Comment: Has anybode ever faced this problem? The problem still exists. When I call the service from my server from a laptop in the same wlan, no problems occur. Only when I access the service in my app, there are so many errors like Connection failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)