# ConnectionException: Connection refused

Tags: java, android, database-connection

I need to register with app on my tablet, but when I press the button "register" I get `ConnectionException: Connection refused`.

This is my endpoint:

```
public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://192.168.1.129/android_login_api/register.php";
```

MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


</manifest>
```

I don't know why it doesn't work!

Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android HTTP Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469060/android-http-connection-refused)

Comment: @Omi it is simple:12-14 11:59:03.335 12251-12251/info.androidhive.loginandregistration E/RegisterActivity: Registration Error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: @ThomasEdwin no!

Comment: share connection related register activity code..

Comment: @Omi https://pastebin.com/rKEdngqa

Comment: I guess you try to connect your tablet to your PC. You have to ensure that both devices are connected to the same network. If yes, try to turn off firewall on your PC. And then, using a browser(Chrome, Firefox,...) to connect to the PC.

Comment: if your register.php is hosted locally on PC try running the app on emulator and change IP from 192.168.1.129 to 127.0.0.1

Comment: with postman it works!

Comment: @LQGioan yes, i try to connect tablet to PC

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaShahid but i need use app with tablet not emulator

Comment: connection over wifi? and server like xampp/ wamp?

Comment: @LQGioan i turn off firewall but i get the same problem

Comment: @AswinPAshok server mamp and connection over wifi

Comment: try http://192.168.1.129:port number in your tablets browser

Comment: @AswinPAshok    i get the list of project made with mamp server!

Comment: Not sure about this, add port number in URL_REGISTER like you did with your browser

Comment: @AswinPAshok i forgot the port number after machine IP! THANKS to remember it

Comment: Got it working?