# Android device: how to view all http requests to the Internet?

Tags: java, android

I need a tool (may be an Android application) that displays all current http requests from a device. In my interests is to view all http requests to get mp3 files which (requests) is generated by one application.

So, the tool could allow us to view all http requests or requests of a particular application.

Do you know such a tool?

**Update**.

Yes, there are privacy restrictions to do that. What about the application that was developed by me? Can I escape the restrictions and view traffic of the application? May be using some debug tools?

Comment: @njzk2 I do not see the app for android in the market.

Comment: Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons, except via rooted devices using tools like Wireshark, or possibly via a proxy server (if you are going through WiFi and if the app supports a proxy server or you are on a device that supports WiFi proxies). You are also welcome to set up the classic Wireshark on your router or something, and have the device set up to go through WiFi.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you! Can I do that if I load the application using debug tools? I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

> What about the application that was developed by me?

Oh, well, now, that changes things. You should've said that in the first place. :-)

You should be able to set up proxy server support for your own application, assuming that you are [using `HttpUrlConnection`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432984/115145) or [`HttpClient`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4503990/115145).

Then, you need a proxy server that can inspect your HTTP operations. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a popular one for development use, and I am sure that there are others.