# JSON not returning on HTTPPost on Android

Tags: java, android, json, http

I am having problems calling a simple JSON web service from an Android app.  The .execute() completes successfully with an 200-OK Status however I am unable to read any JSON output or text.

For the record, if I HttpPost a regular webpage, like Google.com, I can read and parse all the markup.  Also, I am able to call the complete *urlWithParams* string from the device's browser and I see JSON output in the browser.  This works in device's browser:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false

When the code runs, the reader is always blank and reader.readLine() never runs.  Returns an empty string.  If I change the URL to Google.com, it works and returns 17,000 characters.  Thanks!

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

    String responseString = null;   

    try {
                //String urlGoogle = "http://google.com";
                //String urlWithParams = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false";
                String urlOnly = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json";
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlOnly);

                httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("origins", "Seattle"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("destinations", "Cleveland"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sensor", "false"));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append((line + "\n"));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                responseString = sb.toString();
                }}
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        } 

        return responseString;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not that good with web but i think if you can retrieve it with providing a link in browser and the "?" sign its a get not post

Comment: @Warlock Tried using a GET and the same results happen.  reader2.readLine()) == null.  See here: http://pastebin.com/Yd9z9PRp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  The blank return when calling the JSON page was due to not having the proxy settings defined.  Proxy settings were setup on the device however [per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503437/android-httpclient-doesnt-use-system-proxy-settings), HttpClient does NOT inherit them.

Adding the following line resolved my issue.  The code is now returning JSON.

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("172.21.31.239", 8080);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should test other mime types instead of application/json.

Comment: Other than "Content-type", "application/json", what do you recommend?  And why would it not be "application/json"?

Comment: "application/json" is probably right. But you can test with other mime types.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Check in your manifest file having INTENET Permission or not.

2 - Use this code its returning data

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
try {
        String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    responseString   += inputLine;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
try {
is.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

Comment: 1 - I have INTERNET in my AndroidManifest.xml file: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

2 - I tried your block of reader code, but responseString is still null after it runs.