# Video play on android phone

Tags: video

I want to know how my android app will stream videos in US. Now I am in India, is there any way to test how video stream in US? I have already used FakeGPS app to make the required setup, but this will not change the IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use proxy in your **httpClient**, here a nice answer: [Android HttpClient Doesn't Use System Proxy Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503437/android-httpclient-doesnt-use-system-proxy-settings)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am searching for some external support. Is there any app in android which will make a setup of device being in US?

Comment: @doubt, you can ask in chat (http://chat.stackoverflow.com) in any Android room, but you need more reputation to talk.