# Can the Xamarin Android HTTP client be made to use the system proxy settings where present?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

The xamarin android http client ignores system proxy settings !?? [This old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503437/android-httpclient-doesnt-use-system-proxy-settings) prompted a number of people to answer how the proxy could be set directly, but I don't want to set it directly. I want to recover and use the system values, if present.

Does anyone have a neat way of doing this?